# Nginx Redirect Help

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I wanted to use NginxHttpMapModule and NginxRedirect to redirect static links to dynamic php links.

I want to redirect http://my_domain/static/static_page1.html to http://domain_name/dynamic/zone.php?zoneid=86 by looking up the url from a map table.

I tried this but it ends in a redirect loop.

```
map_hash_bucket_size 256;
    map $uri $dynamic_url {
        default 42;
        /static/static_page1.html 86;
        /static/static_page2.html 36;
    }
    server {
        listen       80;     
        server_name  domain_name;
            rewrite ^ http://domain_name/dynamic/zone.php?zoneid=$dynamic_url break;
    }
```

Please help me with this.
Regards,
Shain

Answer (score 1):

```
rewrite ^/static http://domain_name/dynamic/zone.php?zoneid=$dynamic_url break;
```

Answer (score 0):

What's most likely happening there is that you do not have a server block for domain_name. Since you use server_name _ it will catch all requests that do not have a more specific server block.

So Nginx gets the request, rewrites it, then gets the request in the same server block and your infinite loop has begun.